# Nodejs winston miss logs

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am trying to use winston for my nodejs application.

Wrote the following test:

```
for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){
   logger.info("test"):
}
```

But winston will not write all of it. It just stops around 3k+.

Has anyone got this issue? How to fix it. I was using file transport with maxsize option.

Answer (score 1):

Just subscribe to the logger error event and see if the logger is throwing some error.
For eg.

```
logger.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("Error while logging message to file error : " + err);
});
```